# Java how to access inner enum class

Tags: java, enums

```
public class Constant {

  ......

  public enum Status {
    ERROR,
    WARNING,
    NORMAL
  }

  ......

}
```

After compiling I got a class file named **Constant$Status.class**. The question is, how can I access the enum value. For instance, I want to get the string representation of the ERROR status.

Comment: `Constant.Status status = Constant.Status.NORMAL;` doesn't work ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You'll be able to access it elsewhere like

```
import package.name.Constant;
//...
Constant.Status foo = Constant.Status.ERROR;
```

or,

```
import package.name.Constant;
import package.name.Constant.Status;
//...
Status foo = Status.ERROR;
```

---

To get the declared name of any `enum` element, use [`Enum#name()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29):

```
Status foo = ...;
String fooName = foo.name();
```

Comment: if an enum is a member of a class, it is implicitly static - there's no need for the static keyword.

Answer (score 6):

In your code just do:

```
Constant.Status.ERROR.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this was not mentioned before, in the original question the `enum` has the `public` access modifier which means we should be able to do `Constant.Status.ERROR.toString()` from anywhere. If it was set to `private` it would have been available only to the class: `Constant`. Similarly it is accessible within the same package in case of no modifier (default).

Comment: What 'outer enum'?