# Jenkins/Groovy: How to declare/use an enum outside class?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, enums, jenkins-shared-libraries

I have a Jenkinsfile that calls function `setup()` from shared-lib `my_lib`:

```
// Jenkinsfile
@Library('my_lib@dev') my_lib

import groovy.json.JsonOutput

pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage( "1" ) {
      steps {
        script {
          d = my_lib.setup();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The shared-lib function tries to assign enums to dictionary elements.

```
// vars/my_lib.groovy
def setup() {
  def d = [:]
  d.a = org.foo.Foo.Event.A  // ok
  d.b = my_enum.getEvent()   // ok
  d.c = my_enum.Event.A      // groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Event for class: my_enum
}
```

```
// src/org/foo/Foo.groovy
public class Foo {
  enum Event {
    A,
    B;
  }
  def Foo() {}
}
```

`my_enum.groovy` declares an enum, and a getter-function that returns one of those enums:

```
// vars/my_enum.groovy
public enum Event {
  A,
  B;
  def Event() {}
}

def getEvent() { return Event.A }
```

**Problem**:
The above code fails in `my_lib.groovy` at `d.c = my_enum.Event.A` with error `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Event for class: my_enum`

**Questions:**
Why does assigning `my_enum.Event.A` fail?
How do I define and use a "file-scoped" enum?
Why does assigning an enum scoped to `my_enum` fail when a class-scoped enum is okay, and also a simple wrapper function in `my_enum` that returns `Event.A` also okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1/ Why does assigning my_enum.Event.A fail?**

here is a plain groovy code that approximately corresponds to `my_enum.groovy`  from your question in jenkins/groovy

```
class MY_ENUM {               // <- this class is not accessible for you in jenkins
  enum Event {A,B}
  def getEvent() { Event }    // <- i have changed this func on purpose 
}
def my_enum = new MY_ENUM()   // <- however my_enum variable is visible for you in jenkins

println MY_ENUM.Event.A       // works in plain groovy, but MY_ENUM class is not accessible in jenkins
```

to access inner enum in java/groovy you have to use `CLASSNAME.ENUMNAME.KEY` accessor - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280937/java-how-to-access-inner-enum-class)

but `MY_ENUM` is not accessible for you in jenkins to do this `MY_ENUM.Event.A`

and when you are accessing `my_enum.Event.A` - you are trying to get `Event` from instance of the class instead of class itself - so, it fails

**2/ How do I define and use a "file-scoped" enum?**

with function getEvent() defined as in class above you could do this:

```
my_enum.getEvent().A
```

or this - groovy will find getEvent() function for this accessor

```
my_enum.event.A
```

not sure but try to define `my_enum.groovy` like this:

```
enum Event {A,B}
return Event
```

then this should work:

```
my_enum.A
```

**3/ Why does assigning an enum scoped to my_enum fail when a class-scoped enum is okay**

because each file in jenkins results an instance of class but class itself is not accessible.